# Lightweight Rendering Pipeline error

Tags: runtime-error, shader, lightweight-processes

I downloaded the lightweight rendering pipeline using *Unity's package manager*, but I cannot create a lightweight pipeline asset. When I try to create the asset, the console throws me:

> Invalid generated unique path 'ProjectSettings/LightweightAsset.asset'
>   (input path
>   'LightweightAsset.asset')UnityEngine.Experimental.Rendering.LightweightPipeline.LightweightPipelineAsset:CreateLightweightPipeline()

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but it went away after I did the following:

- Using the new package manager: Remove all rendering-related packages from the Unity project and then only add the Lightweight
  Rendering Pipeline package. All dependencies (like the Shader Graph) were
  added automatically and correctly after I did that.
- Be sure to get the newest preview release (1.1.5-preview or newer). The 0.1-releases are too old.

If all else fails, try to follow the instructions and clone it directly from the Github repository: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/ScriptableRenderPipeline